# How to write a Django query on a confusing traversal that goes backward in M2O then forward to M2M

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to get all orders for a user in which the user is either part of the order's vendor's representatives or managers.

I'll explain better with some code. Here is the relevant part of my `models.py`

```
class Vendor( models.Model ) :
    managers        = models.ManyToManyField( User, related_name = 'managers'       , limit_choices_to = { 'userprofile__user_types' : 4 } )
    representatives = models.ManyToManyField( User, related_name = 'representatives', limit_choices_to = { 'userprofile__user_types' : 5 }, null = True, blank = True )

class Order( models.Model ) :
    creator  = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'creator' )
    approver = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'approver' )
    vendor   = models.ForeignKey( Vendor, null = True, blank = True )

class UserType( models.Model ) :
    name = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )

    # id |       name
    #----+------------------
    #  1 | tenant
    #  2 | property manager
    #  3 | property owner
    #  4 | vendor manager
    #  5 | vendor
    #  6 | viewer
    #  7 | moderator
    #  8 | administrator

class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    user       = models.OneToOneField( User )
    user_types = models.ManyToManyField( UserType, null = True, blank = True )
```

To get all the orders that a user created it's easy:

```
Order.objects.filter( creator = user.pk )
```

The reason I couldn't figure out how to get this one is because I couldn't figure out how to `filter` with an OR-clause (manager *or* representative) or check of existence in a M2M relationship (check if part of managers/representatives list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all, to explain those two bits of syntax: to OR in filters, you use `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q
results = MyModel.objects.filter(Q(name='daniel') | Q(status='fantastic'))
```

and to test membership in a ManyToMany, you just use `=`

```
results = MyModel.objects.filter(user__name='daniel')
```

which means "has a user whose name is daniel" (and not, as you might think, "has only one user, ie daniel").

So, to put these together, you can do:

```
Order.objects.filter(Q(vendor__managers=my_user) | 
                     Q(vendor__representatives=my_user))
```

Comment: Why do you need to go `managers__user`? Are you trying to go forward from `Vendor.managers` to `User`? Can I just stop at `managers` (ie `vendor__managers = my_user.pk`)?

Comment: @hobbes3 quite right, sorry, corrected above. I was confused by the inclusion of the UserProfile in your code, and assumed the M2Ms were pointing there rather than directly to User. Apologies.

Comment: No, thank you! I just want to make sure I was getting it :-). Since `vendor_managers` is a list of numbers in a M2M SQL cross-table, I thought I needed to check with `my_user.pk`, but I don't really need to?